# Changing node value in XSLT depending on conditions

Tags: xslt

I'm new in XSLT and have a problem with converting values. 
I have XML node:

```
<NPD>0</NPD
```

type in XSD:

```
<xs:element name="NPD" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
```

I've created XSLT visualisation using Altova StyleVision but now I have to change in NPD node value "0" to string "No" and value "1" to string "yes".

How can I obtain this effect?

```
<td colspan="3" style="padding-left:10px; width:1.40in; ">
    <xsl:for-each select="$XML">
        <xsl:for-each select="wnio:DD">
            <xsl:for-each select="wnio:NPD">
                <span style="color:#0024c0; ">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </span>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <span>
        <xsl:text>&#160; </xsl:text>
    </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use template rules:

```
<xsl:template match="wnio:DD[.='0']">No</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wnio:DD[.='1']">Yes</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xsl:choose` to perform if/switch like statements in XSLT.  Here's an example which should work for your scenario:

```
<xsl:template match="NPD">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="./text()='0'">
            <xsl:text>No</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="./text()='1'">
            <xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message terminate="yes">The Yes/No value to be translated did not match expected input</xsl:message>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_choose.asp for more.

That said, [Michael Kay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101554/361842)'s way better; beautifully elegant & to the point.